# Makefile: using cp command while reading from a file

Tags: linux, makefile, wildcard, cp

In makefile, I am doing something like this -

```
@while read -r file; do \
    if [ ! -z "$$file" ]; then \
        cp -R path/to/someplace/$$file path/to/someplace/else/$$file \
        fi \
done <filename.txt
```

filename.txt contains files and folders like -

```
abc/*.txt
folder1/
folder2/
textfile.txt
```

I am able to copy files and folders but in the case of `abc/*.txt` it shows an error:

```
cp: target `/path/to/someplace/else/*.txt' is not a directory.
```

Is there some way possible to copy these files with wildcard characters?

Comment: You should first decide if `filename.txt` contain file paths or patterns to be [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))ed, and code differently the two cases.

Comment: Test if `$$file` is a directory via `if [ -d ...]`. If it is, use `cp -R`, otherwise just use `cp` with destination `$(dirname "..")`.

Comment: Read the [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/). The expansion of a command happens once only, not more. Your `filename.txt` don't contain file paths as you pretend, but something to be further expanded by [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). So I claim that your `filename.txt` is wrong (or refer to some non-existent file with a `*` in its path)

Comment: Remember that `*` could appear in a file name, even if that is very poor taste. See [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is not in the pattern expansion. That bit would appear to work as expected. The error is actually due to the resulting `cp` command. You end up with for instance:

```
cp abc/a.txt abc/b.txt other/path/abc/*.txt
```

However, for multiple source files `cp` expect destination to be a directory, which `other/place/abc/*` is not (it could be if you created it, but is unlikely what you wanted).

That said. You could for instance create the target directory by calling `` mkdir -p other/path/`dirname $$file` `` (escaped `$` for make) and with `cp` use  `` `dirname $$file` `` as well for destination.

There are few caveats. For instance if absolute paths were to be encountered or globing characters where also used on directories leading up to the files themselves (`dir?/*.txt`, `some/*/file`). It would perhaps be safer to use for instance `tar` or `cpio`:

```
tar cf - -C /source/path src/*.txt  | tar xf - -C /target/path/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There were no globing characters in the directories so I used `mkdir -p other/path/dirname $$file` and then copied the files.